# How can I link data coming from an API to a column in a data table in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There is a data table which is getting data from an API.

This API is responsible for populating every column on the data table. I added a new column named "Project Involved" which should get filled by the data "ProjectNames" coming from API.

The problem that am facing is- I am not able to link this data to the column on data table.

There are other columns that are getting populated.

This is the column name:

```
{
      data: 'ProjectsInvolved',
      title: $translate.instant('Projects involved'),
      width: 80
}
```

This is where we link the API to the data table:

```
"use strict";

angular
  .module('project')
  .controller(
    'ProjectPermissionsGridController',
    function (
      $scope,
      roleConstants,
      $timeout,
      FormHelperService,
      $translate,
      $mdDialog,
      logger,
      projectConstants,
      DateHelperService,
      ResourceService,
      ProjectService,
      $stateParams,
      $filter
    ) {
      var pm = this;
      pm.resources = [];
      pm.copyOfAllResources = [];
      pm.pmFormBtn = $translate.instant('btn.save');
      pm.projectMemberList = [];
      pm.IsProjectManager = false;
      pm.maxAllowedHoursLimit = projectConstants.PROJECT_COST_PER_HOUR;
      pm.projectMembersData = {
        EmpID: '',
        Read: roleConstants.NONE,
        Write: roleConstants.NONE,
        IsProjectManager: false,
        // ProjectNames: pm.projectMemberList.ProjectNames
        ProjectNames: ''
      };

      pm.showNoErrorsPerm = true;
      pm.maxDate = DateHelperService.setTimeFormattedObject(new Date());
      var currentIndex = '';
      pm.isProjectMemberEdit = false;
      var oldProjectMemberData = {};

      pm.udpateResourcePersmissions = function () {
        if (pm.projectMembersData.IsProjectManager) {
          pm.projectMembersData.Read = roleConstants.ALL;
          pm.projectMembersData.Write = roleConstants.ALL;
        }
      };

      pm.initDataTableConfig = function (column, config, api) {
        $scope.dtColumns = column;
        $scope.dtConfig = config;
        $scope.dtApiProjectMembers = api;
      };

      // Catching the event and binding the data
      $scope.$on('evt.project-member-details', function (e, projectMembers) {
        pm.projectMemberList = projectMembers;
        pm.bindDataToGrid(false, projectMembers);
      });

      $scope.$on('evt.resources-list', function (e, resources) {
        pm.resources = resources;
        pm.copyOfAllResources = resources;
      });

      // On change to remove the cost per hour required  validation.
      pm.removeCostperHourValidation = function () {
        if (!pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour) {
          pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour = null;
        }
        if (
          parseFloat(pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour) >
          pm.maxAllowedHoursLimit
        ) {
          pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour = pm.maxAllowedHoursLimit;
        }
      };

      /**
       * Add / update new data to project members grid.
       */
      pm.addNewProjectMember = function (valid, $event) {
        if (!valid) {
          $scope.showNoErrorsPerm = false;
          return false;
        }

        pm.projectMembersData.ProjectMember =
          FormHelperService.getSelectedObject(
            pm.resources,
            'EmpID',
            pm.projectMembersData.EmpID,
            false
          ).EmpFirstName +
          ' ' +
          FormHelperService.getSelectedObject(
            pm.resources,
            'EmpID',
            pm.projectMembersData.EmpID,
            false
          ).EmpLastName;
        pm.projectMembersData.ReadText = projectConstants.PERMISSION_TYPE_OBJ[
          pm.projectMembersData.Read
        ]
          ? projectConstants.PERMISSION_TYPE_OBJ[pm.projectMembersData.Read]
          : '--';
        pm.projectMembersData.WriteText = projectConstants.PERMISSION_TYPE_OBJ[
          pm.projectMembersData.Write
        ]
          ? projectConstants.PERMISSION_TYPE_OBJ[pm.projectMembersData.Write]
          : '--';
        // pm.projectMembersData.ProjectsInvolved = 'OSMOSYS';

        if ($scope.isProjectEdit) {
          membersEditProjectForm();
        } else {
          memberNewProjectForm($event);
        }

      };

      /**
       * Function to be executed in the new project page.
       * @param {*} event
       */
      function memberNewProjectForm($event) {
        // Setting this value at the time of clicking on edit button.
        if (pm.isProjectMemberEdit) {
          oldProjectMemberData = {};
          angular.extend(
            pm.projectMemberList[currentIndex],
            pm.projectMembersData
          );
          pm.pmFormBtn = $translate.instant('btn.add');
        } else {
          pm.projectMembersData.CreatedOn =
            DateHelperService.setTimeFormatString(new Date());
          pm.projectMemberList.splice(0, 0, pm.projectMembersData);
          // remove that element from employees dropdown to not to select it again
          enableOrDisableEmployee(pm.projectMembersData.EmpID, true);
        }
        angular.element($event.target).data('isInvalid', true);
        $scope.showNoErrorsPerm = true;
        pm.projectMembersData = {
          EmpID: '',
          Read: roleConstants.NONE,
          Write: roleConstants.NONE,
          IsProjectManager: false,
          ProjectNames: ''
        };
        pm.bindDataToGrid(!pm.isProjectMemberEdit, pm.projectMemberList);
        $scope.updateProjectMembers({ projectMembers: pm.projectMemberList });
        pm.isProjectMemberEdit = false;
      }

      /**
       * Function to add a new project member
       * @param {*} data
       * @param {*} projectMemberDetails
       */
      function addProjectMember(data, projectMemberDetails) {
        ProjectService.addProjectMember(data).then(function (response) {
          if (response.isValid()) {
            pm.projectMemberList.splice(0, 0, pm.projectMembersData);
            pm.bindDataToGrid(false, pm.projectMemberList);
            enableOrDisableEmployee(pm.projectMembersData.EmpID, true);
            resetPMForm();
            $scope.$emit('evt.update-project-managers', projectMemberDetails);
            logger.success('Resource has been added to the project');
          } else {
            var errorMsg = response.getMessage(
              $translate.instant('prj.resource'),
              $translate.instant('event.adding')
            );
            logger.error(errorMsg);
          }
        });
      }

      /**
       * Function to update a project member's details
       * @param {*} data
       * @param {*} projectMemberDetails
       */
      function updateProjectMember(data, projectMemberDetails) {
        ProjectService.updateProjectMember(data).then(function (response) {
          if (response.isValid()) {
            angular.extend(
              pm.projectMemberList[currentIndex],
              pm.projectMembersData
            );
            pm.pmFormBtn = $translate.instant('btn.add');
            pm.bindDataToGrid(pm.isProjectMemberEdit, pm.projectMemberList);
            enableOrDisableEmployee(pm.projectMembersData.EmpID, true);
            $scope.$emit('evt.update-project-managers', projectMemberDetails);
            resetPMForm();
            pm.isProjectMemberEdit = false;
            logger.success("Project member's details have been updated.");
          } else {
            var errorMsg = response.getMessage(
              $translate.instant('prj.project_members_details'),
              $translate.instant('event.updating')
            );
            logger.error(errorMsg);
          }
        });
      }

      /**
       * Function to be executed in the project details form
       */
      function membersEditProjectForm() {
        var projectMemberDetails = {
          empID: pm.projectMembersData.EmpID,
          name: pm.projectMembersData.ProjectMember,
          isProjectManager: pm.projectMembersData.IsProjectManager,
        };
        var members = [];

        // Adding the projectCode to project member's data
        pm.projectMembersData.ProjectCode = $stateParams.projectID;

        // Creating the UserID property as the add and update project members API methods expects the UserID and not
        // the EmpID
        pm.projectMembersData.UserID = pm.projectMembersData.EmpID;

        // Adding the current project memeber to the members array as the API methods for the
        // add and update project member expects an array
        members.push(pm.projectMembersData);
        if (pm.isProjectMemberEdit) {
          updateProjectMember(members, projectMemberDetails);
        } else {
          addProjectMember(members, projectMemberDetails);
        }
      }

      pm.eleFocus = function () {
        FormHelperService.searchElementFocus();
      };

      // Clearing the searched item when closing the dropdown
      pm.clearSearchTerm = function () {
        pm.projectMemberSearchText = '';
      };

      /**
       * return the search results for auto complete controls.
       */
      pm.querySearch = function (
        query,
        list,
        listObjProp,
        listObjPropName,
        splitObjProp
      ) {
        if (!list || list === '') {
          list = [];
        }
        if (listObjPropName) {
          var queryObj = {};
          queryObj[listObjPropName] = query;

          if (splitObjProp) {
            var listOjProp = listObjProp.split('.');
            pm[listOjProp[0]][listOjProp[1]] = $filter('filter')(
              list,
              queryObj
            );
          } else {
            pm[listObjProp] = $filter('filter')(list, queryObj);
          }
        } else {
          pm[listObjProp] = $filter('filter')(list, query);
        }
      };

      // Fetching the row and row index when clicking on edit button and showing the details in form
      angular.element('table').on('click', '.edit-project-member', function () {
        pm.projectMembersData = $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.getRowData(
          this.parentElement
        );
        pm.IsProjectManager = pm.projectMembersData.IsProjectManager;
        if (pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour) {
          pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour =
            typeof pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour === 'string'
              ? pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour
              : pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour.toFixed(2);
        }
        if (pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour) {
          pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour =
            typeof pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour === 'string'
              ? pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour
              : pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour.toFixed(2);
        }

        // Adding the code as IsProjectManager property is mandatory and sometimes may not be defined
        if (!pm.projectMembersData.IsProjectManager) {
          pm.projectMembersData.IsProjectManager = false;
        }
        angular.copy(pm.projectMembersData, oldProjectMemberData);
        pm.isProjectMemberEdit = true;
        pm.pmFormBtn = $translate.instant('btn.update');
        currentIndex = $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.getRowIndex(
          this.parentElement
        );
      });

      // Showing an alert and Deleting the row data
      angular
        .element('table')
        .on('click', '.delete-project-member', function () {
          var deleteRowIndex = $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.getRowIndex(
            this.parentElement
          );
          var deleteRowData = $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.getRowData(
            this.parentElement
          );
          showConfirmDialog(deleteRowIndex, deleteRowData);
        });

      function showConfirmDialog(deleteRowIndex, deleteRowData) {
        var confirm = $mdDialog
          .confirm({
            onComplete: function afterShowAnimation() {
              var $dialog = angular.element(
                document.querySelector('md-dialog')
              );
              var $dialogContent = $dialog.find('md-dialog-content');
              var $actionsSection = $dialog.find('md-dialog-actions');
              var $cancelButton = $actionsSection.children()[0];
              var $confirmButton = $actionsSection.children()[1];
              angular.element($dialogContent).addClass('custom-confirm-class');
              angular.element($confirmButton).addClass('md-raised md-warn');
              angular.element($cancelButton).addClass('md-raised');
            },
          })
          .title($translate.instant('prj.confirm_pm_delete'))
          .textContent(
            'Are you sure you want to delete the selected project member?' +
              deleteRowData.ProjectMember
          )
          .ariaLabel($translate.instant('prj.confirm_pm_delete'))
          .ok($translate.instant('bar.delete'))
          .cancel($translate.instant('bar.cancel'));

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
          pm.isProjectMemberEdit = false;
          if ($scope.isProjectEdit) {
            var projectMemberData = [
              {
                ProjectCode: $stateParams.projectID,
                UserID: deleteRowData.EmpID,
              },
            ];
            ProjectService.deleteProjectMember(projectMemberData).then(
              function (response) {
                if (response.isValid()) {
                  logger.success(
                    $translate.instant('prj.project_member_removed_success_msg')
                  );
                  deleteProjectMember(deleteRowIndex, deleteRowData);
                  if (deleteRowData.IsProjectManager) {
                    $scope.$emit(
                      'evt.project-manager-removed',
                      deleteRowData.EmpID.toString()
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  var errorMsg = response.getMessage(
                    $translate.instant('prj.project_member'),
                    $translate.instant('event.deleting')
                  );
                  logger.error(errorMsg);
                }
              }
            );
          } else {
            deleteProjectMember(deleteRowIndex, deleteRowData);
            $scope.updateProjectMembers({
              projectMembers: pm.projectMemberList,
            });
          }

          pm.pmFormBtn = $translate.instant('btn.save');
          pm.projectMembersData = {
            EmpID: '',
            Read: roleConstants.NONE,
            Write: roleConstants.NONE,
            IsProjectManager: false,
          };
        });
      }

      function deleteProjectMember(deleteRowIndex, deleteRowData) {
        pm.projectMemberList.splice(deleteRowIndex, 1);
        pm.bindDataToGrid(false, pm.projectMemberList);

        var oldEmpId = deleteRowData.EmpID;

        // Add that element to employees dropdown to be able to select it again
        enableOrDisableEmployee(oldEmpId, false);
      }

      function enableOrDisableEmployee(empId, isEnable) {
        for (var j = 0; j < pm.resources.length; j++) {
          if (pm.resources[j].EmpID === empId) {
            pm.resources[j].isDisabled = isEnable;
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      pm.isReadPermissionLevelLess = function (level) {
        return pm.projectMembersData.Read < level ? true : false;
      };

      /**
       * To change the write permission default value based on the read permission
       * Ex : If read - own, then write should not be all
       */
      pm.changeWriteDefaultValue = function () {
        if (pm.projectMembersData.Read < pm.projectMembersData.Write) {
          pm.projectMembersData.Write = pm.projectMembersData.Read;
        }
      };

      /**
       * Get the cost per hour of an employee when the employee value is changed
       */
      pm.getCostPerHour = function () {
        ResourceService.getEmployeeCostPerHour(
          pm.projectMembersData.EmpID
        ).then(
          function (response) {
            if (response.isValid()) {
              var costPerHour = response.getData();
              if (costPerHour && costPerHour[0]) {
                pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour =
                  costPerHour[0].CostPerHour.toFixed(2);
                pm.projectMembersData.CostPerHour =
                  pm.projectMembersData.EmpCostPerHour;
              }
            }
          },
          function (error) {
            logger.error(error);
          }
        );
      };

      $scope.$on("evt.clear-pm-members-grids-data", function () {
        pm.projectMemberList = [];
        pm.bindDataToGrid(false, pm.projectMemberList);
      });

      // Binding the data to grid with updated data.
      pm.bindDataToGrid = function (reOrder, projectMembers) {
        pm.projectMemberList = projectMembers;
        if (pm.projectMemberList && pm.projectMemberList.length) {
          var currPage = $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.getPageInfo()['page'];
          $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.bindData(pm.projectMemberList);
          currPage = currPage >= 0 ? currPage : 0;
          if (reOrder) {
            $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.orderByColumn([[1, 'desc']]);
          } else {
            $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.setPage(currPage);
          }
        } else {
          $scope.dtApiProjectMembers.bindData([]);
        }
      };

      function resetPMForm() {
        $scope.showNoErrorsPerm = true;
        $scope.vm.pmData.$setPristine();
        $scope.vm.pmData.$setUntouched(true);
        pm.projectMembersData = {
          EmpID: '',
          Read: roleConstants.NONE,
          Write: roleConstants.NONE,
          IsProjectManager: false,
        };
      }

      $scope.$on('evt.reset-project-members-form', function () {
        resetPMForm();
      });
    }
  );
```

I tried linking data when adding new resource- I can see project getting linked. I hard coded this to see if I was working on the right container.